# Can't add int to ArrayList of integers

Tags: java

I'm supposed to create a new array, which contains the first element of arrays a and b (excpet if one is empty, I must skip it). The problem is that when I try to add the int element to the ArrayList I get the error:
"incompatible types: java.util.ArrayList cannot be converted to int[]"
This is so annoying..
Here's the code:

```
public int[] front11(int[] a, int[] b) {
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
if (a.length>0 & b.length>0){
    list.add(a[0]);
    list.add(b[0]);
}
if (b.length==0 & a.length>0){
    list.add(a[0]);
}
if (b.length>0 & a.length==0){
    list.add(b[0]);
}
return list;
```

}

Comment: What's the type of `list`? What's the return type of your method?

Comment: `list` is **not** an `int[]`.

Comment: You should declare `list` as an `int[]` and not use `add` on it.  In fact, using `ArrayList` is making this harder, not easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ArrayList` is not an array, no matter the name of the class. It's named that way because it uses an array internally to manage the list.

Using an `ArrayList` is also overkill here. You have 4 scenarios, so just code them and create the returning array as needed:

```
public static int[] front11(int[] a, int[] b) {
    if (a.length > 0 && b.length > 0)
        return new int[] { a[0], b[0] };
    if (a.length > 0)
        return new int[] { a[0] };
    if (b.length > 0)
        return new int[] { b[0] };
    return new int[0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`list` is not an `int[]` and you don't need a `List` here. Nor do you need an instance, so I'd make it `static` and I would do it inline (and I would also guard against `null`). Like,

```
public static int[] front11(int[] a, int[] b) {
    int alen = (a != null) ? a.length : 0, blen = (b != null) ? b.length : 0;
    if (alen > 0 && blen > 0) {
        return new int[] { a[0], b[0] };
    } else if (alen > 0) {
        return new int[] { a[0] };
    } else if (blen > 0) {
        return new int[] { b[0] };
    } else {
        return new int[0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert int[] return type into `ArrayList<Integer>`

```
    public ArrayList<Integer> front11(int[] a, int[] b) {
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
if (a.length>0 & b.length>0){
    list.add(a[0]);
    list.add(b[0]);
}
if (b.length==0 & a.length>0){
    list.add(a[0]);
}
if (b.length>0 & a.length==0){
    list.add(b[0]);
}
return list;
}
```

Comment: This is NOT a fully formed answer. Where is the code to do this?

Comment: public ArrayList<Integer> front11(int[] a, int[] b) {
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
if (a.length>0 & b.length>0){
    list.add(a[0]);
    list.add(b[0]);
}
if (b.length==0 & a.length>0){
    list.add(a[0]);
}
if (b.length>0 & a.length==0){
    list.add(b[0]);
}
return list;

Comment: method will be return list of ArrayList<Integer>